# Laravel merge arrays into one

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables and I want to make 1 array of both tables data.

#### Logic

1. User has bids
2. Either user is bidder which results come from `bids` table based on `user_id` column
3. Or user is owner and received bids which comes from `projects` table based on `user_id` column
4. I want to merge this 2 arrays into 1 (regardless of user being bidder or receiving bids, I want get all bids at once)

#### Code

This is what I have currently, but it's not good solution in case user is both bidder and owner, with current code user will only receive data of his/her bids as bidder only.

```
$bids = Bid::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->with(['project', 'project.user', 'user'])->get();
if(count($bids) > 0) {
    return response()->json([
        'data' => BidsResource::collection($bids),
        'message' => 'Your data is ready.'
    ], 200);
} else {
    $projects = Project::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id');
    $bids = Bid::whereIn('project_id', $projects)->with(['project', 'project.user', 'user'])->get();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => BidsResource::collection($bids),
        'message' => 'Your data is ready.'
    ], 200);
}
```

I have already tried `array_merge` but it return errors (details below).

```
// as bidder
$bids1 = Bid::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->with(['project', 'project.user', 'user'])->get();
// as project owner
$projects = Project::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id');
$bids2 = Bid::whereIn('project_id', $projects)->with(['project', 'project.user', 'user'])->get();
// merge results
$bids = array_merge($bids1, $bids2);

return response()->json([
  'data' => BidsResource::collection($bids),
  'message' => 'Data is ready.'
], 200);
```

`array_merge Errors`

1. Code above return `array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given`
2. If I add `->get()->toArray();` then it would return `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

**Any suggestions?**

#### Update

`BidsResource` file

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $arrayData = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'amount' => $this->amount ?  "$ " .number_format($this->amount, 0) : "$0",
        'note' => $this->note,
        'attachment' => $this->attachment ? url('images', $this->attachment) : null,
        'accepted' => $this->accepted,
        'results' => $this->results,
        'user' => new UserResource($this->whenLoaded('user')),
        'project' => new ProjectsResource($this->whenLoaded('project')),
        'chats' => BidChatsResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('chats')),
        'created_at' => $this->created_at ? $this->created_at->diffForHumans() : null,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at ? $this->updated_at->diffForHumans() : null,
    ];
    return $arrayData;
}
```

Comment: Technically, array_merge works ok. I presume it has something to do with `BidsResource::collection($bids)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, the proper and efficient way would be using an `OR` clause to get the records where either of the conditions is satisfied.

The code would be

```php
$projects = Project::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('id');
$bids = Bid::where(function($query) use ($projects, $user){
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->orWhereIn('project_id', $projects);
})->with(['project', 'project.user', 'user'])->get();
```

Comment: it says `Undefined variable: user` in `->orWhereIn('user_id', '=', $user->id)` i think `whereIn` expects array.

Comment: Oh sorry! I messed up the order. I have edited it, Please check now. (Please also ignore the 3rd condition in function if you see any... I have removed it in latest edit)

Answer (score 0):

As the results of `$bids1` and `$bids2` are objects of laravel collection, you can use `merge()` method of [collections#method-merge](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge)

```
$bids = $bids1->merge($bids2);
```

Comment: it says `Call to a member function merge() on array`

Comment: You're querying `Bid` model, if you're using eloquent, the result must be a laravel collection, unless you converted it to array using `toArray()`.